# Users cannot run executables on network shares on XP

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, network-share, file-permissions

User A is in group 1.
Group 1 has Full Control over a network shared folder that contains an executable (Office installation).
User A gets the error: "... The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again." on Windows XP.
Windows 7 works fine.
Add user to Domain Admins group, XP works fine.

If I add Group 1 to the Administrators group on the network share PC, it works. Why would it be checking against the local admins group of that PC when its being executed via the network?

Basically, what group does User A need to be in to execute remote executables from a network share on XP?

Comment: When and how is this running?  How is the execution being initiated?

Comment: Make or use the group other than "Administrators" or "Domain Admins" and give that group execute permissions on the file/executable.

Comment: Via a network share, just navigating to the file then double clicking it. Group 1 has Full control over the folder and executable and the user is in that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the share as a drive and see if the user can run the executable from the mapped drive. I've seen setups that just didn't work over a share on XP.

also, if you just put the user in the group, they may need to log out and back in to pick up the new AD group membership.

Comment: I did this, and it did work. Is there any way to get it to work besides mapping the drive?

Comment: If you can run the executable as administrator then it may be fixable.  If the executable's inner workings just can't deal with UNC paths and are hard-coded to deal with drive letters then no. I'd just make a batch file that maps a drive letter, runs the program, and then drops the map. I map to "B:" in install scripts since no one has two floppy drives anymore. ;-)

Comment: If it's a problem with the executable why does it work fine in Windows 7?

Comment: I think, given that it works in 7, that it is an XP issue. The shell there didn't like UNC paths as the current directory. I dug up this article on M$... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276  That could be a red-herring though. The issue tends to come up in multi-installers that call other internal installs because they call multiple levels of scripts from inside other scripts.

Comment: Definitely possible. This solution will just have to work for now, thats what we get for still being on XP.